# MVVM - how do I pass context to the repository class?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I'm trying to learn MVVM, and I faced some issue which I don't know how to resolve. I wanted to make a repository which will get user coordinates in background thread. The thing is in order to make it work, I have to pass context for it, but I don't know how to pass context for repository. I can't just pass it that easily like in some activity class.

**Repository**

```
    public class LocationRepository {
    
    private void test() {
        
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(CONTEXT);
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CONTEXT, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(CONTEXT, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null){
                            //TODO
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    }, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to pass a Context to create a `FusedLocationProviderClient`. You should pass/inject `FusedLocationProviderClient` via the constructor. Using DependencyInjection you can create `FusedLocationProviderClient` once (from ApplicationContext) and pass it to whoever needs it. Otherwise you can pass the context from Activity/Fragment to ViewModel to Repository.

Comment: Currently I'm not using any DependencyInjection. Is the second way that you meantioned is actually an answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this if you do not wanna use Dependency Injection.

**This is a minimal example leaving lots of stuff open for improvements!**

In this example we not gonna pass down the `Context` as this can lead to memory leaks (if not thoroughly handled) but creating the `FusedLocationProviderClient` in the Activity and passing it to the ViewModel and the Repository.

*Note: Avoid passing Android related things like `Context`, `View`'s etc down to your ViewModel and lower layers. It will make testing and refactorings easier, because you less depend on Android.*

In your Activity you get your ViewModel and you create your `FusedLocationProviderClient`:

```java
public class YourActivity : Activity() {

  private FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this.applicationContext);

  // Either you pass FusedLocationProviderClient via constructor to the ViewModel, or via a setter later
  private YourViewModel viewModel = // ...       

  override void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     // if you wanna set the locationProvider via setter
     viewModel.setLocationProvider(locationProvider); // this should not leak when the activity finishes as there is no reference to the Activity or its view 
  }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel you either get the `locationProvider` via Constructor or a setter:

```java
public class YourViewModel extends ViewModel {
  
  // You can either create a new LocationRepository in the viewModel,
  // or you can pass an instance via Constructor (which I recommend for better testability)
  // or you pass it via a setter
  private LocationRepository locationRepository;

  public YourViewModel(FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider) {
    locationRepository = new LocationRepository(locationProvider);
  }

  // alternatively using a setter
  public void setFusedLocationProviderClient(FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider) {
    locationRepository = new LocationRepository(locationProvider);
  }

  // this function calls your repository
  public void foo() {
    // ensure LocationRepository is initialized or you will get a Nullpointer here,
    // or check if (locationRepository != null) { ... } before accessing it
    localRepository.test()
  }

  @Override
  public void onCleared() {
    // do cleanup
    // stop ongoing work (in your repository)
    // unregister listeners (in your repository)
  } 
}
```

```java
public class LocationRepository {

  private FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider;

  public LocationRepository(FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider) {
    this.locationProvider = locationProvider;
  }

  public void test() {
    // ... now you can use FusedLocationProviderClient (without the need of having a context
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Much appreciate.