# How to pass context in Repository in MVVM without DI and following the clean architecture?

Tags: android, mvvm, clean-architecture

I need to initiate Room in its repository. But to do that I need context. If I pass context through the viewmodel i got this message  `This field leaks a context object`.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506697/mvvm-how-do-i-pass-context-to-the-repository-class) answer but they init the repository object in the view layer but according to the clean architecture view layer shouldnt know anything about data layer right? So how to organize the delivery of the `context` to the data layer without DI?

```
class MainViewModel(private val context: Context) : ViewModel() {

private val roomManager : RoomManager = RoomManagerImpl(context)

private fun addItem(){
    roomManager.addItem()
}
```

}

Here is repository code

```
class RoomManagerImpl(private val context: Context) : RoomManager {
private val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
)
```

Comment: @HanifShaikh how

Comment: i think don't need it. use repository in side the  ViewModel parameter

Comment: @HanifShaikh dont understand. Please provide example

Comment: You'd use `AndroidViewModel` which have `application` param that you'd pass to the Repository; its context is applicationContext which is relevant to the app lifecycle; I think it shouldn't have leak, can you test that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing Activity Context to the Activity's ViewModel is not a good practice  it will cause memory leak.

You can get the context in your ViewModel by extending the **AndroidViewModel** class check below code.

It will give you application level context.

```
 class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
    private val roomManager: RoomManager = RoomManagerImpl(context)

    fun addItem() {
        roomManager.addItem()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      class MainViewModal(val repository:roomManager) :ViewModel() {
            
            fun testFunction(context: Context){
            roomManager.testMethod(context)   //text method is your repository method
        }
    }
```

i am telling like this I hope it's help you otherwise you can use [AndroidViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451819/how-to-get-context-in-android-mvvm-viewmodel) instead of Viewmodal